# gdal_translate GTiff drivers does not support NUM_THREADS creation option

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, mosaic

I am using `gdal` to stitch together google earth engine tiles (35 tiles, roughly 100 gigs altogether).

First I build a VRT

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

# Build a VRT
os.system('gdalbuildvrt /scratch/user/output.vrt /scratch/user/MODIS_NDVI_TIFF/*.tif')
```

Then I use `gdal_translate` to stitch them together with various creation options to help with processing speed:

```
os.system('gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -a_nodata 0 -of GTIFF -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=1 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 -co INTERLEAVE=BAND /scratch/user/output.vrt /scratch/user/MyBigNastyRasty2.tif')
```

Specifically, I would like the resulting image to be a GeoTiff. However, I am getting this warning:

`Warning 6: Driver GTiff does not support NUM_THREADS creation option`

This is curious because the [gdal website says that this format can use this creation option](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html).

I am using gdal version 2.3.3. Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: The gdal_translate command that you have inside your code works for me with GDAL versions 2.4.4 and 3.2.0. The option is documented to be supported already in GDAL 2.1. Check again your version with `gdalinfo --version`.  If it is high enough and still fails, try to upgrade, there may be something odd in your installation.

Comment: Good point. I'll update to version 3.2.0 and report back.

Comment: You were right! Something funky was going on with the version.